# Where to put the stellar.toml file in a React App?

Tags: stellar.toml

After locking the created coin, we are trying to validate the coin with the stellar.toml file with in the apps directory. All though with no avail. What would be the proper way to initialize the stellar.toml file within a React app? We were assuming that having the file in the public directory would be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As describe [in the documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html), `stellar.toml` should be in the `.well-known` folder. So if your domain is `DOMAIN`, the complete url is

```
https://DOMAIN/.well-known/stellar.toml
```

If your react app is served at `https://DOMAIN/`, then you should make a `.well-known` folder in the root and add the `stellar.toml` there.

Comment: Thank you Francesco, we were having CORS issues and came to the conclusion that the netlify.toml file was not pushing the header configs. Instead we created an `_headers` file in the root directory with: 

`# the stellar.toml file route
/.well-known/stellar.toml  
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Content-Type: text/plain`

This solved the Cors issue and everything is working!